# Python code to remove HTML tags from a string

Tags: python, html, xml, string, parsing

I have a text like this:

```
text = """<div>
<h1>Title</h1>
<p>A long text........ </p>
<a href=""> a link </a>
</div>"""
```

using pure Python, with no external module I want to have this:

```
>>> print remove_tags(text)
Title A long text..... a link
```

I know I can do it using **lxml.html.fromstring(text).text_content()** but I need to achieve the same in pure Python using builtin or std library for 2.6+

How can I do that?

Comment: Any specific reason why you don't want to use an external module.?

Comment: no permissions to install modules on the server...

Answer (score 435):

### Using a regex

Using a regex, you can clean everything inside `<>` :

```
import re
# as per recommendation from @freylis, compile once only
CLEANR = re.compile('<.*?>') 

def cleanhtml(raw_html):
  cleantext = re.sub(CLEANR, '', raw_html)
  return cleantext
```

Some HTML texts can also contain entities that are not enclosed in brackets, such as '`&nsbm`'. If that is the case, then you might want to write the regex as

```
CLEANR = re.compile('<.*?>|&([a-z0-9]+|#[0-9]{1,6}|#x[0-9a-f]{1,6});')
```

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56490838/4168707) contains more details on this.

### Using BeautifulSoup

You could also use `BeautifulSoup` additional package to find out all the raw text.

You will need to explicitly set a parser when calling BeautifulSoup
I recommend `"lxml"` as mentioned in alternative answers (much more robust than the default one (`html.parser`) (i.e. available without additional install).

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
cleantext = BeautifulSoup(raw_html, "lxml").text
```

But it doesn't prevent you from using external libraries, so I recommend the first solution.

EDIT: To use `lxml` you need to `pip install lxml`.

Comment: if you want to compile regexp, best way is compile outside function. In you exemple every call `cleanhtml` must be compile regexp again

Comment: BeautifulSoup is good when the markup is heavy, else try to avoid it as it's very slow.

Comment: Great answer. You forgot the colon at the end of `def cleanhtml(raw_html)` though :)

Comment: FWIW, this will also remove XML another XHTML tags, too.

Comment: if you want to remove specific tags only you could either <tag>.extract() them to remove tag+content or <tag>.clean() it to remove only the tag... There is no syntaxic difference between a html tag and and xml tag.

Comment: Nice answer. You might want to explicitly set your parser in BeautifulSoup, using `cleantext = BeautifulSoup(raw_html, "html.parser").text`

Comment: what's the importance of compiling the pattern if we can just pass it as a string to re.sub() ?

Comment: re.sub() is a regex function that requires a patern to match every kind of tags. Backward it compiles it...

Comment: '<.*?>' can anyone explain what it will do.

Comment: . any character   * multiple time ? optional characters (non greedy for parser means it is not obliged to find one) basically what this expression does is to concentrate on the formal caracter that express a tag i.e < and > matching everithing that has < and >

Comment: Compiling the regex is not needed since it is cached automatically.

Comment: regex fail when use w3c standar, by example: `<!-- <div> -->` or `<plaintext>` or `< bad header <html> bad footer >` or `<\s` or `<%`, etc.

Comment: The first half of this answer should be removed because it is terribly wrong to try this. HTML needs to be parsed as a tree and understood that `<script>` and other tags can contain anything. I say this with the politest regard and c24b acknowledged this.

Comment: "Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml"

Comment: Install python-lxml to find the tree builder

Answer (score 51):

Python has several XML modules built in. The simplest one for the case that you already have a string with the full HTML is [`xml.etree`](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html), which works (somewhat) similarly to the lxml example you mention:

```py
def remove_tags(text):
    return ''.join(xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring(text).itertext())
```

Comment: This worked for me but be carefull of the html tags from autoclose type.
Example : </br>

I got a "ParseError: mismatched tag: line 1, column 9" cause this tag is close without being open before. This is the same for all html tags autoclosed.

Answer (score 40):

Note that this isn't perfect, since if you had something like, say, `<a title=">">` it would break. However, it's about the closest you'd get in non-library Python without a really complex function:

```
import re

TAG_RE = re.compile(r'<[^>]+>')

def remove_tags(text):
    return TAG_RE.sub('', text)
```

However, as lvc mentions [`xml.etree`](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) is available in the Python Standard Library, so you could probably just adapt it to serve like your existing `lxml` version:

```
def remove_tags(text):
    return ''.join(xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring(text).itertext())
```

Comment: I like your regex approach, maybe it will be better if performance's an important factor.

Comment: And in addition, it works with strings not starting with an xml tag, it that would be the case

Comment: @DouglasCamata regex is not more performant than an xml parser.

Comment: @SlaterTyranus that depends on the xml parser and regex implementation.  I guess both use C extensions... but do you have any benchmarks for us to see?

Comment: @DouglasCamata It's hard because the two aren't really comparable. It's easy to come up with toy examples where `regex` will outperform a real parser, but these lxml benchmarks are a good indicator of real-world performance http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-hiperfparse/

Comment: It's worth noting that this will break if you have a text `<` in your document.

Comment: For the `xml.etree` solution, I get `NameError: name 'xml' is not defined`, any ideas?

Comment: @PatrickT you need to export it - `import xml.etree`

Comment: @Amber, thanks! I misunderstood the meaning of "available in the Python Standard Library" as always available.

Comment: a slight improvement to the original answer can be `re.sub(<[^<]+?>, '', text)`

Answer (score 9):

There's a simple way to this in any C-like language. The style is not Pythonic but works with pure Python:

```
def remove_html_markup(s):
    tag = False
    quote = False
    out = ""

    for c in s:
            if c == '<' and not quote:
                tag = True
            elif c == '>' and not quote:
                tag = False
            elif (c == '"' or c == "'") and tag:
                quote = not quote
            elif not tag:
                out = out + c

    return out
```

The idea based in a simple finite-state machine and is detailed explained here: http://youtu.be/2tu9LTDujbw

You can see it working here: http://youtu.be/HPkNPcYed9M?t=35s

PS - If you're interested in the class(about smart debugging with python) I give you a link: https://www.udacity.com/course/software-debugging--cs259. It's free!

Comment: This will break on mismatched quotes, and is quite slow due to adding to the output character by character. But it ilustrates enough, that writing a primitive character-by-character parser isn't a big deal.

Comment: This answer is great for teaching HTML or Python, but misses a crucial point for production use: meeting standards is hard, and using a well-supported library can avoid weeks of research and/or bug-hunting in an otherwise healthy deadline.

Answer (score -14):

```
global temp

temp =''

s = ' '

def remove_strings(text):

    global temp 

    if text == '':

        return temp

    start = text.find('<')

    end = text.find('>')

    if start == -1 and end == -1 :

        temp = temp + text

    return temp

newstring = text[end+1:]

fresh_start = newstring.find('<')

if newstring[:fresh_start] != '':

    temp += s+newstring[:fresh_start]

remove_strings(newstring[fresh_start:])

return temp
```

Comment: Your answer is: a) awfully formated (violates pep8 for example), b) overkill because there are tools to do the same, c) prone to fail (what happens when html has > character in one of the attributes?), d) global in XXI century in such trivial case?