# How do I parse this output in flask?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, flask, jinja2

[image]

I want to parse the description portion of the code. how can i do that in jinja? The relevant code is as follows :

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    window.onload=function (){
    $("#searcher").submit(function(ev) {

    /* stop form from submitting normally */

        ev.preventDefault();



        $.post("/searchRSS", $("#searcher").serialize(),function(o){console.log(o);document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=o;});
})};
</script>
<form id="searcher" method="post" action="#">
<input type="text" id="query" name="query" required/>
<input type="submit" value="Get Feed"/>
</form>
<div id="result">
    <table>
        {% for row in posts %}
        <tr><td>{{ row.title }}</td></tr>
        <tr><td>{{ row.date }}</td></tr>
        <tr><td>{{ row.description }}</td></tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
</div>
```

The code that manages searchRSS is as follows :

```
@app.route('/searchRSS',methods=['POST'])

def search_results():
    feed = feedparser.parse("http://news.google.com/news?hl=en&gl=in&q="+request.form['query']+"&um=1&output=rss" )
    print feed['feed']
    posts = []
    for i in range(0,len(feed['entries'])):
        posts.append({
            'title': feed['entries'][i].title,
            'date': feed['entries'][i].updated,
            'description': feed['entries'][i].description

        })
    print  posts
    return render_template('index.html', posts=posts)
```

By parsing I mean i Want to just show the relevant information not the HTML/CSS tags.

Comment: What do you mean by parse?

Comment: Can you post the code that manages the `searchRSS` endpoint?  (Or even better, what it is returning?)

Comment: @SeanVieira i have edited the answer as you advised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The news items that you are requesting come encoded as HTML.

If you want to convert them to plain text I can think of two possible options:

1. strip the HTML tags (see the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9662346/python-code-to-remove-html-tags-from-a-string) for a possible solution)
2. scrape the text out of the HTML using a tool such as [BeatifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)