# How to strip tags from html with robobrowser

Tags: python, django, beautifulsoup, robobrowser

I'm experimenting with http://robobrowser.readthedocs.org/en/latest/readme.html, a new python library based on the beautiful soup library. with some help, I have returned an html page within a django app, but I can't figure out to strip the tags to give me just the text .
My django app contains :

```
def index(request):    

    from django.utils.html import strip_tags
    p=str(request.POST.get('p', False)) # p='https://www.yahoo.com/'
    browser = RoboBrowser(history=True)
    browser.open(p)
    html = browser.response
    stripped = strip_tags(html)
    return HttpResponse(stripped )
```

when I look at the outputted html I see that it is the same as the original html. Also I don't think robobrowser has the text() method of beautiful soup.

I also tried (from [Python code to remove HTML tags from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9662346/python-code-to-remove-html-tags-from-a-string)):

```
def remove_html_markup(s):
    tag = False
    quote = False
    out = ""    

    for c in s:
            if c == '<' and not quote:
                tag = True
            elif c == '>' and not quote:
                tag = False
            elif (c == '"' or c == "'") and tag:
                quote = not quote
            elif not tag:
                out = out + c    

    return out
```

Same result! How can I remove the html tags and return the text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BeautifulSoup provides the `soup::get_text()` method for extracting text from a parsed HTML document (somewhat confusingly, this is equivalent to the `getText` method and the `text` property). You can access the parsed HTML of the current page using `browser.parsed`. So, to get the plain text of the current page, try

`text = browser.parsed.get_text()`

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using [`bleach`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bleach).

Here's some example code:

```
import Bleach
varName = ( bleach.clean( result.find_all( class_ = 'className' ),
                          strip  = True
                          )
            ).strip( '[])' )
```