# Remove html entities and extract text content using regex

Tags: regex

I have a text containing just HTML entities such as `&lt;` and `&nbsp;` I need to remove this all and get just the text content:

```
&nbspHello there&lt;testdata&gt;
```

So, I need to get `Hello there` and `testdata` from this section. Is there any way of using negative lookahead to do this?

I tried the following: `/((?!&.+;).)+/ig` but this doesnt seem to work very well. So, how can I just extract the required text from there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are 2 suggestions:

1) Match all the entities using `/(&.+;)/ig`. Then, using whatever programming language you are using, replace those matches with an empty string. For example, in php use [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php); in C# use [Regex.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1(v=vs.110).aspx). See this SO for a similar solution that accounts for more cases: [How to remove html special chars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657643/how-to-remove-html-special-chars)

2) If you really want to do this using the plaintext portions, you could try something like this: `/(?:^|;)([^&;]+)(?:&|$)/ig`. What its actually trying to do it match the pieces between`;` and `&` with special cases for start and end without entities. This is probably not the way to go, you're likely to run into different cases this breaks.

Comment: Thanks, tried 2-Just got back from the looney bin. I'll go with 1.

Answer (score 24):

A better syntax to find HTML entities is the following regular expression:

```
/&([a-z0-9]+|#[0-9]{1,6}|#x[0-9a-fA-F]{1,6});/ig
```

This syntax ignores false entities.

Comment: This doesn't necessarily matter, but it's worth noting that this is technically not comprehensive. `&amp`, `&#123`, and `&#000000000000000000123;` are all valid HTML entities that won't be matched by this.

Comment: [a-z0-9]+ matches &amp and similar forms, and #[0-9]{1,6}  matches all entities from &#0 to &#999999 .  I think other forms are not useful.

Comment: It matches `&amp;`, not `&amp`. Your regex requires a semicolon, but `&amp` is a valid HTML entity. And I didn't say anything about whether those forms of entities are useful. I only said this regex is not comprehensive. If someone needed a comprehensive regex for their use case, this would not work.

Answer (score 1):

It's language specific but in Python you can use `html.unescape` ([MAN](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html)). Like:

```
import html
print(html.unescape("This string contains &amp; and &gt;"))
#prints: This string contains & and >
```

Answer (score 0):

After a short look at the python documentation one can come across the `html.parser` module: https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html#module-html.parser

And after some short prototyping one can come up with the fairly simple code:

```py
from html.parser import HTMLParser

line_with_html = 'Data before tag with <span style="color:var(--md-font-color-green)">some gren text</span> with a nice logo'


class CleanHTML(HTMLParser):
    def reset(self) -> None:
        self.extracted_data = ""
        return super().reset()

    def remove_tags(self, html_data: str) -> str:
        """
        Args:
            html_data (str): HTML data which might contain tags.

        Returns:
            str: Data without any HTML tags. Forces feeding of any buffered data.
        """
        self.reset()
        self.feed(html_data)
        self.close()
        return self.extracted_data

    def handle_data(self, data: str) -> None:
        """
        Args:
            data (str): Html data extracted from tags to be processed.
        """
        self.extracted_data += data


p = CleanHTML()
print(p.remove_tags(line_with_html))
```

No need to:

- Use regular expression
- Use third-party modules like BeautifulSoup
- Use parsers whih were not intended for HTML, like the XML parser