# "Dave&#39 s Market" to "Daves Market"

Tags: regex, option-type

I have some strings like "Dave&#39 s Market" or "C&#39 est la vie" I would like to convert to "Daves Market" and "Cest la vie" respectively.   I know it is something like '[&#39]+' but I cannot get the optional " s" to be just "s".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove html entities and extract text content using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26127775/remove-html-entities-and-extract-text-content-using-regex)

Comment: Try `&#[0-9]+\s+`

Comment: @Vasan May not be, since in this case the OP may want to convert the text instead of remove; i.e. actually want to have "Dave's Market" instead of "Daves Market"

Answer (score 1):

The regex substitution `s/&#39 //g` should work, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/nQoGd2/1).

Comment: Maybe replace the hard-coded `39` to a generic `[\d]+`?

Comment: I don't see that requirement in the question. I personally would think one would want to decode them instead of removing them, but if the OP wants &#39 removed, I'll remove &#39; and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

What you'd rather want is something like replacing all those escaped literals with what they should actually be, e.g.:

```
Dave&#39;s -> Dave's
Me &#38; Her -> Me & Her
```

Then you'll have to use some kind of replacement code and regex.

An example(in JavaScript):

```
var m = new Map();
m.set("&#39;", "'");
m.set("&#38;", "&");
// and so on

m.forEach(function(value, key) {
    // text contains your text
    text = text.replace(new RegExp(key), value);
}
```