# Fix regex expression used to replace all \n and \r inside quotes

Tags: javascript, regex, linefeed, capturing-group

This might be hard to explain, I will do my best. I am currently working on a csv transform stream parser in nodejs, but I am struggling in replacing all \n's and \r's inside quotes (") that wrap a value.

At the moment I have the following regex:

```
(^|[;])"(?:""|[^"])*[\n\r]+(?:""|[^"])*"
```

Where ; is the column delimiter.

And here is two examples, the first one where its doing what is expected and the second one where its capturing but it shouldn't because the ; is inside quotes.

**First Test (success)**

```
test;"123";"this description with new line feed  below should be
matched by regex";test;"1.0"
```

**Second Test (error)**

```
NewLine1;"test - this one should not be captured by the regex but its being captured&nbsp;";test;1
NewLine2;"test that went wrong"
```

Is there a way to pick the text that is between quotes, containing semicolon before first quote and containing semicolon after last quote, but ignore semicolon inside quotes? I think that's what I need , so the second example is not take into account for the regex match.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to parse the CSV first, and then run your regex over the individual values instead?

Comment: changing regex into `(^|[;])"(?:""|[^";])*[\n\r]+(?:""|[^";])*"` must work. https://regex101.com/r/2JXXWJ/1

Comment: I can't parse first @NiettheDarkAbsol, its huge, I stream it and save it line by line.

Comment: Thanks @mjrezaee sounds like an easy fix, I will test it with a large sample and see if I came into any other issues. Also please use that as an asnwer, so I can proper accept it later :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use:

`(^|;)"(?:""|[^";])*[\n\r]+(?:""|[^";])*"`

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/2JXXWJ/2)

I changed `[;]` to `;` because they're equivalent in your case. Also added `;` character to `[^";]` because your CSV stream column value, can't have this character.

I don't know why you have `""` in the regex but if you seek considering other double quotes in the column value, i assume they must be escaped by `\` and so you can use regex like `(^|;)"(?:(?<=\\)"|[^";])*[\n\r]+(?:(?<=\\)"|[^";])*"` that has `(?<=\\)"` instead of `""` which indicates `"` character preceding with back slashes. (`\"`)

Comment: I notice now that I may have a quoted column with new line feed and a semicolon inside that I want to still apply the regex replace to delete the new line, I believe I should only avoid the cases like HTML entities such as &nbsp; | &quot; | &apos; and so on to the remaining ones, is it possible to still catch the semicolon and avoid those cases? thanks

Comment: @TiagoM see if `(^|;)"(?:""|&[a-z0-9]+;|[^";])*[\n\r]+(?:""|&[a-z0-9]+;|[^";])*"` (https://regex101.com/r/2JXXWJ/3) works for you. `&[a-z0-9]+;` detects html entity syntax. `&[a-z0-9]+;` can be more complete based on your case. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/56490838/13900748 if you have `#x` html entity syntax.

Comment: Sorry for the trouble and confusion, but going with html entity syntax actually is not a good idea now that I am aware, because if I have another column delimiter in other cases it won't work. But I think I don't have much options here, what I must enforce to the csv provider is to not send any column delimiter inside quotes otherwise it won't work with the regex you provided (^|;)"(?:""|[^";])*[\n\r]+(?:""|[^";])*" on the answer. Like you see in this link https://regexr.com/59ou7 the first two lines should be captured but not the two ones below, but there isn't a way to differentiate..

Comment: @TiagoM yes, you must have some limit in your input if you want to parse regex like this, else, you can face real problems.

Comment: I have an idea, I do a pre-processing with a first regex to remove any column delimiter inside quotes, and then apply your regex, that might work.