# Remove encoded HTML tags from large string in Python

Tags: python, html, string, parsing, replace

I have a JSON file with a "description" key in it, that has lots of HTML tags inside. I would like to erase them. They're encoded, like:
`&lt;ul&gt;` instead of `<ul>`

I've tried doing `text.replace('<.*?>','')`, but it doesn't work.
I've also tried with BeautifulSoup doing:

```
text = soup.get_text()
```

But it doesn't work neither (it just only decodes the html tags)
And finally, I've tried doing:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(text)
text = soup.get_text()
text = text.replace('<.*?>','')
```

Combining that two codes, but the tags won't get deleted...

What I have now in "text" variable (after using beautiful soup that decodes the html tags):
`"description":"</li></ul><p> </p><p><strong>TESTING AND QUALITY</strong></p><ul><li>....."`

What I want to have in text variable:
`"description":"TESTING AND QUALITY"`

Comment: Your code doesn't work because `text.replace()` doesn't recognize regular expressions.  It's looking for the literal text `<.*?>`, which of course isn't there.

Comment: This might be what you're looking for - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9662346/python-code-to-remove-html-tags-from-a-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using regular expressions instead of `replace` to discard the HTML tags:

```
import re

soup = BeautifulSoup(text)
text = soup.get_text()
text = re.sub(r'<.*?>', '', text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `decode_contents()` instead