# Extracting text from a succession of strings enclosed in HTML tags and strings without tags

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Consider the following HTML:

```
<li>
  <a href="url">
    <b>This</b>
    " is "
    <b>a</b>
    " test "
    <b>string</b>
    "!"
  </a>
</li>
```

I would like to extract all the text between the `<a>` tag except `"!"`. In other words, the text contained between the first opening `<b>` and last closing `</b>`:  `This is a test string`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<li>
<a href="url">
<b>This</b>
" is "
<b>a</b>
" test "
<b>string</b>
"!"
</a>
</li>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
anchor = soup.a
```

Note that the number of `<b>` tags and strings without tags varies so `next` or `next_sibling` won't work.

Is there an easier way to do this?

**Edit:**
Ideally, I would like a method that works even if I have more than one string not enclosed in tags after the last `</b>`.

Comment: Perhaps `[c.text if isinstance(c, element.Tag) else str(c) for c in anchor.contents[:-1]]` where element is `from bs4 import element`

Comment: @Justin Ezequiel Thank you for your suggestion. This would work in my example but not if I have more than one string not enclosed in tags after the last `</b>`, which may occur. I reckon my "attempt" example is a bit confusing because it makes it look like I always have a single string at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the code below

```
result = ''.join([i.strip().replace('"', '') for i in anchor.strings if i.strip()][:-1])
print(result)
```

output

```
'This is a test string'
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. This works in this particular case. Unfortunately it won't work if I have more than one strings not enclosed in tags after the last `</b>`.

Comment: I will accept your answer if I don't get any other since your answer works with the example I provided. That said, if you know a way to deal with this without slicing with a specific number, that would be great.

Comment: @Junitar I have updated the answer, hope this solution covers your concerns.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question and comments, I think getting the indexes of substrings and operating on a whole subset of the HTML could do what you need.

Let's create a function to [retrieve all of the indexes of a substring first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34445090/4413406) (see answer by @AkiRoss):

```
def findall(p, s):
    i = s.find(p)
    while i != -1:
        yield i
        i = s.find(p, i+1)
```

Then use this to find occurences of `<b>` and `</b>`.

```
opening_b_occurrences = [i for i in findall('<b>', html)]
# has the value of [21, 40, 58]
closing_b_occurrences = [i for i in findall('</b>', html)]
# has the value of [28, 44, 67]
```

Now you can use that information to get a substring of HTML to do your text extraction on:

```
first_br = opening_b_occurrences[0]
last_br = closing_b_occurrences[-1] # getting the last one from list
text_inside_br = html[first_br:last_br]
```

The text in `text_inside_br` should now be `'<b>This</b>\n" is "\n<b>a</b>\n" test "\n<b>string'`. You can clean it now, for example by appending `</br>` back to it and using BeautifulSoup to extract the values or just [using regex to do that.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9662346/python-code-to-remove-html-tags-from-a-string)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. That also works but requires additional steps to clean the output. I assume it would work better than @Shibirraj answer in more complicated cases with a mix of different tag types though.

Comment: @Junitar Glad to help. Yes, depends on the complexity of your use case for sure, if yours is very similar to your example then Shibirraj's solution is great.