# Regex is not removing websites from text data in preprocessing

Tags: regex, text, python-3.7

I am doing text preprocessing and in my text there are websites. I want to remove these but I couldn't do it.

Below is the sample text:

> \n\nWorldwide web (www)\n\nName for the entirety of documents linked
>   through hyperlinks on the Internet; often used as a synonym for the
>   latter26.\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n24\xe2\x80\x83\t**www.sicherheitskultur.at**,
>   Information Security Glossary\n\n25\xe2\x80\x83\tSource of text
>   (partly): KS\xc3\x96: Cyber Risk Matrix -
>   Glossary\n\n26\xe2\x80\x83\t**www.sicherheitskultur.at**, Information
>   Security Glossary\n\n\n\n\n\n23\n'

Websites are visible (in bold) and I want to remove these.

I have tried one code (from StackOverflow answer-[Python code to remove HTML tags from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9662346/python-code-to-remove-html-tags-from-a-string)) but it is not removing these websites.

Below is the codes:

```
def remove_web(text):
    cleanr = re.compile('<.*?.*#>')
    text = re.sub(cleanr, '', text)
    return text
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you try to match `<` and `>` that are missing from your input string?

Comment: Maybe have a go with `www\.[^,]+`, depending on the structure of your data.

Comment: Please follow a regex tutorial, as long as you don't you won't be able to ask regex questions that do not boil down to "please give me the code", and you're more susceptible to using code that will break in unforseen fashion. You wouldn't ask for a C# or javascript implementation of an algorithm without knowing the first thing about the language, so why do this with regex when the language is so much simpler?

Comment: Is website is always the same? If yes, then just `string.Replace("www.sicherheitskultur.at", "")`. Otherwise, google regex for website - there are a lot of answers on stack already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so if you only want to remove this particularly URL, you could use this regex:

```
www\.[a-z]+\.at
```

(Go with David Amar's solution.)

Comment: Thanks David, was in a rush when writing this :)

Comment: @"Piyush Ghasiya" you can test regex here: https://regex101.com/

Comment: Still in a rush, huh ? :) [a-z]*[a-z] is [a-z]+

Answer (score 1):

`www(\.\w+)+`

Explanations :
- first it reads www
- then at least one block like this : a dot + some text (letters, numbers, undescores)

To match more chars in the url (hypens, for example), replace \w by a character set like [a-zA-Z0-9_-] for example