# Removing/editing HTML tags from local file

Tags: javascript, html, parsing, dom, tags

I want to remove/edit several HTML tag in a file.

Minimal example: I have this input HTML file on my disk

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html clang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>test</title>
<style>
.remove-tag { color: #FF0000; }
.remove-div { color: #0000FF; }
</style>
</head>

<body>

<p>Hello world!</p>

<div class="remove-tag">
<p>I just want to remove the open/close div tags</p>
</div>

<div class="remove-div">
<p>I want the remove the div and all its content</p>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

I want to process it so that I get this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html clang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>test</title>
<style>
.remove-tag { color: #FF0000; }
.remove-div { color: #0000FF; }
</style>
</head>

<body>

<p>Hello world!</p>

<p>I just want to remove the open/close div tags</p>

</body>

</html>
```

What's the easiest/most straightforward way to do it in your opinion? I hope to be able to write some sort of script to locally run on a given file to get the output. Or have some software that does it given a list of rules to follow.

I'm quite confident with regex/sed/..., but using these tools is a big NO NO for playing with HTML tags (and can understand why).

I've read about javascript (`getElementsByClassName()`, ...). Made some preliminary steps with javascript, installing Node.js. I can't even open a document to retrieve the elements... Looks like I have to install/import jsdom. I'm kinda stuck...

Read about jQuery. Seen several commands examples, but I don't get how to run them on local files. In generl, I'm a completely noob about jQuery.

Read about HTML parsers. Python seems to have a HTML parser library that I can use to accomplish the task.

Also hoped for a HTML parser software; doesn't look like there is any.

Any other hints?

Comment: Can I define/open/manipulate `document` outside of a browser, with a standalone script?

Comment: I understood the question, you don't want to manipulate code in the browser, but directly in the document. I will redo my comments

Answer (score 0):

try this script:

```
<script>

   var removeTag= document.getElementsByClassName('remove-tag'); 
   for(var i=0; i<removeTag.length;i++){
      var innerHTML =  removeTag[i].innerHTML; 
      let div = document.createElement('div');
      div.innerHTML = innerHTML;
      insertAfter(div,removeTag[i]);
      removeTag[i].remove();
    
      }


         var removeDiv= document.getElementsByClassName('remove-div');  
         for(var i=0; i<removeDiv.length;i++){
            removeDiv[i].remove();
         }



      function insertAfter(newNode, existingNode) {
           existingNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, existingNode.nextSibling);
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: This has to be done via browser, adding the script tag to the HTML file itself, right? How do I call the script to modify the file from inside the file (!!)? Also, I prefer a way to do it outside the browser, from a standalone script.

Comment: this script is for client side if you want outaide browser you most do it in serverside with nodejs or php or c# python ....

Comment: you can change your tag and remove dom tag because dom is for browser and use a server side language tag

Comment: Which is in your opinion the more straightforward approach? (nodejs, C#, python) I have good knowledge of C++, so I can search for a library to manipulate DOM. A script can be a little more easy to develop, since I'll be doing several trial-and-error edits. In this case probably phyton, since I basically know how to use it and already have what's needed to run a script. Your opinion?

Comment: i wrote some code that run in output result of rendered page (html output) and use regular expertion (regex) to remove empty tag and remove especial tag. you can use regex in any language like phthon

Comment: usefull link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9662346/python-code-to-remove-html-tags-from-a-string

Comment: regex is not suggested for these kind of operations. Python has a library to manipulate modules (or so it seems), so I can develop something similar to your example. I'll probably follow this way