# Wordpress how to get advanced custom field content using python and the REST API

Tags: python, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, wordpress-rest-api

I am using a REST API with Python to get custom field content from WordPress.  When I pull a non custom field like "Title", I can successfully render this with the code:

```py
post_title = post_data_dict.get('title', {}).get('rendered', '')
```

However, with a custom field, I haven't been able to figure this out.  Right now my code looks like this:

```py
video_content = post_data_dict.get('acf', {}).get('content', '')
```

**However this contains the HTML formatting.**

Any hints would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found this post that worked for me:
[Python code to remove HTML tags from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9662346/python-code-to-remove-html-tags-from-a-string)

I just used the function:

```
def cleanhtml(raw_html):
    cleanr = re.compile('<.*?>')
    cleantext = re.sub(cleanr, '', raw_html)
    return cleantext
```

So, my new code looked like this:

```py
video_content = cleanhtml(post_data_dict.get('acf', {}).get('content', ''))
```